# mac osx - apache - one website, multiple ports?

Tags: macos, apache, vhosts

I'm building a website on my laptop that needs to be referenced via a custom hostname, instead of deep off of the localhost directory.

I need this site to be referenced locally via http://project.name/

I have this working by having created a new entry in my hosts file as well as a virtual host entry in my apache vhosts conf.

I also want to allow external users to view my site.  They would need to access it by my ip address plus a port number, I imagine.

How do I do this?

I assume 'Listen 8080' needs to be added to apache.conf.

Do I create a new vhosts entry that duplicates the one I created before for the local host name, but with a "localhost:8080" name?  (this smells bad).

Or can the existing vhosts entry be amended to also listen on localhost:8080?

To further clarify, I need:

```
 http://project.name and
 http://localhost:8080
```

to reference the same, exact site.  This is because I need to create the site with a custom host name.  My image references, for example need to start with "/images/example.jpg" instead of relative references. This is because the tech dept would have to do 10 mins of extra work.  :^)

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Why does it have to be 8080, is 80 (the default for http) already in use?

Comment: I need both.  I'm using 8080 to access my site using ip-based:port routing, instead of relative. I could change localhost to point to this site I'm working on, but then I'd mess up all of the other sites on my computer.

Comment: I don't completely understand, but it seems you found your solution, so all is well. Just to make sure though - you are aware you can run an unlimited number of web sites on the *same* port as long as it's the same server software? `localhost:80` being one VirtualHost (like at the moment) and `project.name:80` another, and `someotherproject.name:80` yet another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than specifying a host (such as `localhost`) in your vhost directives, use `*` instead. This will allow you to reach that virtual host via different host names. If you omit `ServerName` from the block completely, that will allow you to hit the same site via `http://localhost:8080`, or from outside the machine via `http://<ip address>:8080`.

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
   # your stuff
</VirtualHost>
```

You can then tune what interface these vhosts use with the `Listen` directive itself:

```
Listen 8080              # you can hit the sites from outside your machine, OR
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080    # no access outside your machine
```

Use `apachectl -S` to double check your vhost settings.

Comment: can I have a vhosts entry that allows both?  i.e. <VirtualHost *:80 *:8080>

Comment: Nope, that will have to be 2 entries. However, you can use `Include` to share the same configuration between those entries. Editing answer...

Comment: Actually, if you simply omit the `ServerName`, you'll hit that virtual host no matter what hostname is used to hit port 8080. Ie, `http://localhost:8080` and `http://192.168.0.123:8080` will both use that virtual host.

Comment: You can also have multiple `<VirtualHost>` entries with the same `host:port` signature...Apache will pick the correct one based on `ServerName`.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#intraextra  implies I can merely have two url patterns in my VirtualHost.